# Problema con variable con método GET

Tags: php

En una opción del menú tengo esto:

```
href="index.php?action=user&userMan=TRUE"
```

Y en php:

```
if ( isset($_GET['userMan']) && !empty($_GET['userMan']) && $_GET['userMan']==TRUE) {
    ECHO "OK";
}
```

Pero si en el link cambio o elimino el **TRUE** siempre se ejecuta el ***if***.
No debería entrar si no cumple con la condición.
**ACTUALIZACION:**
Si hago un `var_dump($_GET['userMan'])` me muestra: ***String(4) "TRUE"*** y entra al ***if***.
Si elimino ***TRUE*** del *href* igual muestra ***String(4) "TRUE"*** y también entra al ***if***.

**ACTUALIZACION 2:**
Lo que quiero es invocar a *user* desde el *href* y dentro del archivo **PHP** ejecutar la funcion según la variable asignada:

*Archivo PHP:*

```
if (userMan==TRUE) -> proceso 1.
if (userTool==TRUE) -> proceso 2, etc.
```

Salvo que no sea la mejor manera de realizar esto.

Si le doy valor: `href="index.php?action=user&userMan=true"`
con esto:

```
if(isset($_GET['userMan']) && !empty($_GET['userMan']) && $_GET['userMan'] === 'true') {
```

Si funciona.

Pero si le quito el valor: `href="index.php?action=user&userMan"`

La url me muestra: `index.php?action=user&userMan=TRUE`

Y muestra el error la **Esta página no funciona**

El $_GET['userMan'] al estar definido toma el valor TRUE pero no logro validarlo en el PHP.

Comment: Qué valor te llega si haces un `echo $_GET['userMan']` antes del if de PHP? De todas formas, en PHP estás haciendo comprobación de valor y no de tipo (utilizas dos iguales `==` en lugar de tres `===`)

Comment: Llega __TRUE__ y muestra __OK__ porque ingresa al __if__. Eso está bien. Pero si elimino el __TRUE__ o pongo otro valor igual entra al __if__. Y en teoría no debería hacer eso.

Comment: Has probado con el triple ===? De todas formas, tal como haces la validación no es necesario isset, ya que lo comparas también en el !empty. Revisa como usar esas dos funciones en el manual de php

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Agrega un `var_dump($_GET);` a tu código, dinos lo que muestra y entonces podremos decirte lo que ocurre. Hay que ver lo que está recibiendo el servidor exactamente en la superglobal `$_GET`. Si es posible explica también lo que quieres comparar, porque parecería que haces algunas comparaciones sin sentido.

Comment: Parece que realmente quieres `$_GET['userMan']==='TRUE'`.

Comment: Cuando eliminas el valor de userMan del href ¿estas actualizando el sitio? Tal parece que lo sigues recibiendo

Comment: Sí, lo actualizo, siempre regresa a string(4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando haces una solicitud por get, todos los parámetros los recibirás como string tal es caso del TRUE, ya que esperas recibir un bool, sin embargo recibes un "TRUE"

Al hacer la comparación, `$_GET['userMan']==TRUE` estas comparando un string vacío y te devuelve true

Para que no entre a la condición debes realizar lo siguiente

```
$userMan = isset($_GET['userMan']) ? $_GET['userMan'] : null;
if ($userMan && $userMan != "" && $userMan == "TRUE") {
    ECHO "OK";
}
```

Comment: Si hago esto *href="index.php?action=user&userMan* igual ejecuta el __if__